# Write a Python program to generate tickets for online bus booking, based on the class diagram given below

Tags: python-3.x

- Initialize static variable counter to 0
- `validate_source_destination()`: Validate source and destination. source must always be Delhi and destination can be either Mumbai, Chennai, Pune or Kolkata. If both are valid, return true. Else return false
- `generate_ticket()`:Validate source and destination. If valid, generate ticket id and assign it to attribute `ticket_id`. Ticket id should be generated with the first letter of source followed by first letter of destination and an auto-generated value starting from 01 (Ex: DM01, DP02,.. ,DK10,DC11). Else, set ticket_id as None.
- Note: Perform case insensitive string comparison

For testing:

- Create objects of Ticket class
- Invoke `generate_ticket()` method on Ticket object
- Display ticket id, passenger name, source, destination
- In case of error/invalid data, display appropriate error message

```py
class Ticket:
    counter=0 
    def __init__(self,passenger_name,source,destination):
        self.__passenger_name=passenger_name
        self.__source=source
        self.__destination=destination
        self.Counter=Ticket.counter
        Ticket.counter+=1
    def validate_source_destination(self):
        if (self.__source=="Delhi" and (self.__destination=="Pune" or self.__destination=="Mumbai" or self.__destination=="Chennai" or self.__destination=="Kolkata")):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def generate_ticket(self ):
        if True:
            __ticket_id=self.__source[0]+self.__destination[0]+"0"+str(self.Counter)
            print( "Ticket id will be:",__ticket_id)
        else:
            return False
    def get_ticket_id(self):
        return self.ticket_id
    def get_passenger_name(self):
        return self.__passenger_name
    def get_source(self):
        if self.__source=="Delhi":
            return self.__source
        else:
            print("you have written invalid soure option")
            return None
    def get_destination(self):
        if self.__destination=="Pune":
            return self.__destination
        elif self.__destination=="Mumbai":
            return self.__destination
        elif self.__destination=="Chennai":
            return self.__destination
        elif self.__destination=="Kolkata":
            return self.__destination

        else:
            return None
```

when `generate_ticket()` method will give false condition I don't want to print `ticket_id` but in my code after the false statement the ticket id does print output.

Comment: but you wrote `if True:`, so the condition is always..... `True`...

Comment: change `if True:` to `if self.validate_source_destination():`

Answer (score 0):

class Ticket:
    counter=0
    def **init**(self, passenger_name, source, destination):
        self.__passenger_name=passenger_name
        self.__source=source.lower()
        self.__destination=destination.lower()
        self.__ticket_id=None
        Ticket.counter+=1

```
def get_passenger_name(self):
    return self.__passenger_name
def get_source(self):
    return self.__source
def get_destination(self):
    return self.__destination
def get_ticket_id(self):
    return self.__ticket_id

def validate_source_destination(self):
    if self.__source== "delhi" and (self.__destination=="mumbai" or self.__destination=="chennai" or self.__destination=="pune" or self.__destination=="kolkata"):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def generate_ticket(self):
    if self.validate_source_destination() == True:
        srcchar=self.__source[0].upper()
        destchar=self.__destination[0].upper()
        if(Ticket.counter<10):
            self.__ticket_id=srcchar+destchar+"0"+str(Ticket.counter)
        else:
            self.__ticket_id=srcchar+destchar+str(Ticket.counter)
    else:
        self.__ticket_id=None
    return self.__ticket_id
```

Answer (score -1):

try this thing:

```py
class Ticket:
    def __init__(self, passenger_name, source, destination):
        self.counter = 0
        self.__passenger_name = passenger_name
        self.__source = source
        self.__destination = destination

        self.Counter = self.counter
        self.counter += 1

    def validate_source_destination(self):
        all_destinations = ["Pune", "Mumbai", "Chennai", "Kolkata"]
        if self.__source == "Delhi" and self.__destination in all_destinations:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def generate_ticket(self):
        if self.validate_source_destination() == True:
            self.ticket_id=self.__source[0]+self.__destination[0]+"0"+str(self.Counter)
            print("Ticket id will be: " + self.ticket_id)
        else:
            return False

    def get_ticket_id(self):
        return self.ticket_id

    def get_passenger_name(self):
        return self.__passenger_name

    def get_source(self):
        if self.__source == "Delhi":
            return self.__source
        else:
            print("You have written invalid soure option")
            return None

    def get_destination(self):
        all_destinations = ["Pune", "Mumbai", "Chennai", "Kolkata"]

        if self.__destination in all_destinations:
            return self.__destination
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: You changed the meaning of `counter`. All tickets will have the same ID `XX00`

Comment: How do you use the class ? send me the main function where your declare the instance of the Ticket class

Comment: Why? It doesn't matter. The point is that `counter` was a static class variable so that each `Ticket` instance created will get a unique ID. You put the `counter` inside the `__init__` so now all tickets have `self.Counter = 0` which is used to generate the tickets...